# Using LINQ to SQL with Views Need to Cast / Convert to Table

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, datacontext

**My SQL Server database contains several views** which are essentially filtered (WHERE) / ordered (ORDER BY) versions of some of the tables i.e. no joins.

An example would be my **Downloads** table, which has a view such as **DownloadsOnlineOnly** e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Downloads WHERE Live = 1 ORDER BY FolderName ASC;
```

I can **drag and drop** these views onto my LINQ to SQL DataContext, and use LINQ to query these views and retrieve data fine...

But the foreign key relationships are not being picked up in my DataContext, so I've lost the ability to:

```
Dim dl as DownloadOnlineOnly = (From r in db.DownloadOnlineOnlies Select r).First

Dim fol as Folder = dl.Folder ' Syntax error as there is no association between 

                              ' DownloadOnlineOnly and Folder in my DataContext.
```

I understand why this is happening, but how can I get around this:

- Without manually adding associations in my DataContext?
- Can I **change the type** of the Entity like changing the return type of an SP on the DataContext?
- Can I **cast or convert** between a DownloadOnlineOnly object and Download object?
- Or some other method?

Apologies if this is a trivial problem, I am relatively new to LINQ.

P.S. I am developing with SQL Server 2008 R2 databases.

Comment: Removed "ASP.NET" tag since the problem seems to be independent of ASP.NET. Also, please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: @JohnSaunders What version of SQL Server I am using? Why have you removed useful information from my post?

Comment: What useful information? I removed the "ASP.NET" tag, which is not relevant to your question, as far as I can see. It looks like you'd get the exact same error if you were using Windows Forms or a Console application.

Comment: @JohnSaunders So I repeat, what version of SQL Server am I using? You have removed that information from my post. It is beneficial to explain your development environment in scenarios as above. People will ask anyway.

Comment: Why are you asking about SQL Server version? The tag I removed was [tag:asp.net]. Do you believe that the fact you were using ASP.NET is relevant to your question? If so, then why?

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that your "PS" included information about the database. I put that part back, and I'm adding the [tag:sql-server-2008-r2] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hook them up manually.  Nothing you can do about it.  Just be thankful you're not using EF, because EF's support of views is even worse.  It assumes any non-null field is part of a Composite primary key.

Comment: @ChrisCannon - I was very clear.  You have to hook up the associations manually, there is no other choice.  You cannot cast to other types, there be dragons there.

Comment: there must be a way, what happens when you union a view to a table?